# Initializing an array in Java in O(1) time

Tags: java, data-structures

Is it possible to initialize an array in java in O(1) time. In C\C++ it is possible because the language doesn't automatically initialize the array to 0. In Java, as far as I know, there's no way to skip the automatic initializing step.

To clarify, what I mean is using a specialized data structure that has all array functionality with the addition of the capability of initializing all array elements to a certain value (like zero) in constant time (in O(1) complexity). This is usually done using 3 uninitialized arrays and a counter.

For More info about this method https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time

Comment: I'm puzzled by the wording of your statement about C / C++.  To my mind, it implies C / C++ can initialize something by not initializing something.

Comment: @James I think OP means *allocate*.

Comment: I believe it is about creating the array instance: since C/C++ apparently does not initialize it, it probably is O(1); since Java does initialize, it needs time - not sure why the title is "Initializing an array in Java in O(1) time"?

Comment: Incorrect: It is *not* possible for C/C++ to initialize an array in O(1) time; it can *allocate* an array in O(1) time, but *initializing* it (ie assigning a 0/null to each element), which in Java is always done, is O(n) in all languages.

Comment: Thanks, @Bohemian.   That way, it does make sense.

Comment: You're generally going to use O(n) time to set the elements of the array _either way_ -- maybe not to all 0s, but to whatever values you want the array to have.  So the total time is O(n) in both languages.

Comment: The IBM 370 had a `MVCL` instruction that could be used to initialize an area of memory. Before using it, information about the area to be initialized would be loaded into registers. So, regardless of the size of memory  to be initialized, the number of CPU instructions used would be the same, or O(1).  But, the number of CPU cycles would be O(n), where n is the size of the area to be initialized.

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is using a specialized data structure that has all array functionality with the addition of the capability of initializing all array elements to a certain value (like zero) in constant time (in O(1) complexity). This is usually done using 3 uninitialized arrays and a counter. @James

Comment: @James The number of CPU cycles would be determined by the memory architecture, for example, a DMA controller might be able to clear memory without CPU intervention.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes but `MVCL` is a 370 *CPU* instruction. You caused me to wonder if an I/O channel for the 360 and it's descendants could be or could have been used to clear or set a value within a block of memory. At the time I wrote the comment, I was wondering if Intel CPU has something similar to the 370's `MVCL`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman To clarify, what I mean is using a specialized data structure that has all array functionality with the addition of the capability of initializing all array elements to a certain value (like zero) in constant time (in O(1) complexity). This is usually done using 3 uninitialized arrays and a counter. For More info about this method https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time. The data structure that is mentioned also supports random access, which means accessing element by index in constant time to either read or modify the element.

Comment: @Bohemian To clarify, what I mean is using a specialized data structure that has all array functionality with the addition of the capability of initializing all array elements to a certain value (like zero) in constant time (in O(1) complexity). This is usually done using 3 uninitialized arrays and a counter. For More info about this method eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/…. The data structure that is mentioned also supports random access, which means accessing element by index in constant time to either read or modify the element.

Comment: The C++ trick isn't really O(1) either, since (for security reasons) the OS will typically zero memory before handing it to your process.

Comment: @James I'm not addressing any particular CPU, I'm saying that making generalizations about memory access is fraught, because there's an arbitrary number of ways it could be handled.

Answer (score 5):

In Java you cannot allocate an uninitialized array.

You can allocate uninitialized memory with the Unsafe.allocateMemory method, which will return a pointer, but this is a **private API** that may become unavailable at any time and it is already partially unavailable [JEP 403](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403).

Answer (score 2):

`T[] arr = new T[n];` will initialize the array with the defaults: null (Object, false (boolean), 0 (int) and so on.

You could do `T[] arr = {a, b, c};` or `T[] arr = new T[]{a, b, c};`.
Which *might* have been implemented better - but is not.

Now consider:

```
int[] arr = new int[100_000];
Arrays.fill(arr, 13);
```

The jave byte code instruction for a new array `anewarray` will normally zero the many elements, despite being overwritten by `Arrays.fill`. Though a JIT or AOT compiler might optimize the combined code in real machine instructions.

The speed loss is relative, as the execution is still fast, and normally array elements should be processed further on.

For *sparse* arrays there are other data structures, like `Map<Integer, Integer>`. Boolean arrays can use the more compact and faster `BitSet`.

In C an array allocation does not necessarily zero the elements: the data may be unitialized or - even worse - reclaimed memory. For that reason java *initializes* arrays: better code quality.

There are some unsafe memory features in java, but it would be senseless to use them. However you can use non-java-heap memory in the newest java version.
With calculations in java, that would even be more slow normally.
So better use C in very critical cases.

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is using a specialized data structure that has all array functionality with the addition of the capability of initializing all array elements to a certain value (like zero) in constant time (in O(1) complexity). This is usually done using 3 uninitialized arrays and a counter.

Comment: A HashMap with a large capacity and a getOrDefault might be acceptable. _Sparse_ arrays (see James answer) can postpone the initialisation, but I think you won't consider that O(1) like the HashMap solution. As the HashMap has the disadvantage of storing the indices, even as Integer Object, that solution is not perfect too. A _memory mapped file_ and an `IntBuffer` is not a likely solution too. Maybe you should reconsider whether O(1) of this faces matters considering the entire processing.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, C, and C++, you could create a data structure that gives the functionality of an array, without allocating memory for an element until it is actually needed. This is sometimes done for very large arrays in which most of the elements will not be used. A sparse array and sparse matrix are examples. It reduces the initialization time at the cost of increasing the time needed to access elements. I'll consider a sparse array for the rest of this post.

Suppose a `SparseNode` has `int index`, `double value`, and possibly other instance variables. The `index` indicates where it would be if it were in a normal array. The `SparseArray` class might include these methods: `public void setValue (int index, double value)` and `public double getValue (int index)`.  I'll ignore the possibility of throwing exceptions.

If the `SparseArray` is backed by a `LinkedList`, use of either of those methods could involve a sequential search of the elements until an element with matching index is found or it is determined the element is not in the array.

If the element is not found, the `getValue` method would return the default value, which would be zero for most sparse array applications. The `set` method would add the element to the list.

In a linked list, you could specify a location of a new element in order to keep them in order. If an array element is not in the list, the search would terminate earlier, although the search would still be O(n) time complexity.

There are ways to improve performance over using a sequential search for every call to `getValue` or `setValue`. If the elements are kept in order, there is the possibility of using a binary search. Another possibility is the use of a search tree, or as another answer suggested, a structure using hash functions.

Comment: I forgot to add that the data structure that I mentioned also supports random access, which means acessing element by index in constant time to either read or modify the element. In my opinion, This is the whole point of using an array.

Comment: To be clear, the intention behind a sparse array is not to reduce initialization time of the array. Sparse arrays are implemented in order to reduce memory use when the need is to have a very large array in which most elements will have some default value.

Comment: You could come close by using a `HashMap` to back the sparse array. A lookup based on hash is said to run in "near constant time".  The best case is O(1), the average case is O(1), but the worst case is O(n).